# What Income tax return document do you provide during UK standard visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, india, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

What Income tax return documents should I add during UK standard visitor visa application? `INDIAN INCOME TAX RETURN ACKNOWLEDGEMENT- ITR 4` or `FORM-4 SUGAM - INDIAN INCOME TAX RETURN`? Can anyone who had experience with a standard visitor visa please help with this? Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer but usually it would be ITR-V/Acknowledgment because that is a single page document and has a standardized format.

Comment: Hello @RedBaron,  I generally receive form 4 in ITR acknowledgment(1 page) e-verified, and for 4-sugam is where you have 9 pages of details of income. So I'm confused.

Comment: Schengen visa checklist specifically asks for ITR-V/acknowledgement but UK has no such guidelines. Hence my guess.